# how to parse comlex json in android

Tags: android, json

How to parse below **JSON** with the help of **volley** library, i want **distance** and **duration** values.I am new in Android

```
 {
       "destination_addresses":[
          "D1, A Block, Sector 59, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India"
       ],
       "origin_addresses":[
          "School Block, Block S1, Nanakpura, Shakarpur Khas, New Delhi, Delhi 110092, India"
       ],
       "rows":[
          {
             "elements":[
                {
                   "distance":{
                      "text":"13.8 km",
                      "value":13751
                   },
                   "duration":{
                      "text":"28 mins",
                      "value":1674
                   },
                   "status":"OK"
                }
             ]
          }
       ],
       "status":"OK"
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried or done any investigating on your own?

Comment: yes! too many times , i am unable to obtain values.

Comment: Then you should post the code of your attempt so people can try to help figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: I don't think there's a better resource on parsing JSON on SO than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: please tell me  better resource on parsing JSON

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Gson` library for that. `Gson` is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. for more refer this https://github.com/google/gson

For Gson With volley, you may get lots of examples on the internet just google it. some of the link

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/04/10/custom-gson-request-with-volley/
https://inducesmile.com/android/android-json-parsing-using-gson-and-recyclerview/
https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley